# Hyperlink for textview in android

Tags: android

I want to create a hyperlink to textview in android. So in my layout I have given `android:clickable="true"` to the textview. Previously it worked for my other layouts. But now it is not working. When I am clicking on the textview it remained as it is.What may be the problem?
      Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class? Here is [explanation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html) from android developers. Also [android:autoLink](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink) property of TextView might be helpful/

Answer (score 1):

You can use textview.setOnClickListener. This is useful for you may be.